# Attach armature only to dog tail

Tags: armature, bones

I'm new to Blender. I have downloaded a dog model, I've put some bones to the tail. Now I can move the armature, but how I can attach it to the model (only the tail)? I have used "Set Parent to With Automatic Weights". but now if I rotate the armature, all the dog wheel!
Thanks!

Comment: Simply add a parent bone to the current parent of the tail bones. The dog body will have to be entirely weighted to this new parent bone.